# How can I animate a Camera Iris animation using CAFilter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, caanimation

I am developing a simple camera app, where I need to animate a camera shutter opening/closing animation. I googled on CAFilter and CATransition, but got confused. How is it going to help me animate? Ex. If I have a view called view, and a method called

`-(void)pressed;`

In my interface. How can I implement an animation in my view using CAFilter? Can anyone even give me any other example of this? Maybe a view 360 degree rotation on the press of a button?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried some examples of using CAFilter etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asked and answered elsewhere on this forum.  Here are some references for you:

This uses CATransition:

[Shutter animation AVFoundation iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370114/shutter-animation-avfoundation-iphone)

That uses @"cameraIris" which is an undocumented Apple API, so apps using it might be rejected.  But it sure looks good.

There's also this 26 MB movie:
http://www.juicybitssoftware.com/2009/08/31/iphone-camera-shutter-animation/